# ansible manipulate file with a date format

Tags: ansible, date, format

In ansible, I would like to manipulate files/directories/archive that are composed or to composed like this:

How would I do that. It seem Ansible is not able to handler that. (I doubt).
So, what I do wrong ?

Ex:

```
- name: create file with a date in name
  file: path=/path/somefile.`date +%y_%m_%d`

- name: unzip a file
  unarchive: path=/path/zomezip.`date +%y_%m_%d`.tar.gz bla bla....
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set a variable, then use it with Ansible's [Jinja2 templating system](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#using-variables-about-jinja2) (it looks like you're trying to do PHP with the dot operator and the backticks)

```
vars:
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d-%H%M') }}"
tasks:
  - name: create file with a date in name
    file: path="/path/somefile{{ date }}"
```

Or use the lookup itself in the templates:

```
  - name: create file with a date in name
    file: path="/path/somefile{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d-%H%M') }}"
```

Comment: Yeah ! This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank`s a lot !

Comment: one problem I had with this approach: the var seems to be more like a macro than a thing that executes once and caches. using it multiple times during one run and I got different answers. (this was from a var in a playbook)

Comment: @tenpn for that you would have to set fact (store into variable) like: `- set_fact: my_time: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d-%H%M') }}"`

Answer (score 20):

Starting with 2.4, you can also use the `strftime` filter ([doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#combination-filters)):

```
# Display year-month-day
{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}

# Display hour:min:sec
{{ '%H:%M:%S' | strftime }}

# Use ansible_date_time.epoch fact
{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(ansible_date_time.epoch) }}

# Use arbitrary epoch value
{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(0) }}          # => 1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try..

```
vars: 
  - a_timestamp: "{{ timestamp.stdout }}"

tasks:
  - name: Get a timestamp
    command: date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
    register: timestamp
```

then add the variable where needed.